# Поиск элемента XPath

Tags: javascript, xpath

На страничке есть такой элемент по содержащему в нем тексту, т.е. нужно составить запрос, что бы в нем был `Jacqueline Cako` и 11/4

```html
<div class="ipe-Participant ">
   <span class="ipe-Participant_OppName">Jacqueline Cako</span>
   <span class="ipe-Participant_OppOdds ">11/4</span>
</div>
```

Как найти именно `div`?

Результатов не дает:

```js
webEngine.executeScript("document.evaluate('//*[contains(text(), \"Jacqueline Cako\") and contains(text(), \"13/8\")]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().innerText;");
```

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Столько времени убил, задал вопрос, тут же нашел то, что мне помогло. 
Решение `document.evaluate('//div[contains(@class, "ipe-Participant") and contains(., "Jacqueline Cako") and contains(., "11/4")]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().innerText;);`